# Usage of 'provided' sub-projects with android gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with a subproject, that should be only in the *compile-time* classpath.

```
root-project
|- classic-subproject
`- compile-time-subproject
```

The root-project uses

```
[...]
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    [...]
    compile project(':classic-subproject')
    provided project(':compile-time-subproject')
}
android {
    [...]
}
```

Both sub-projects use

```
[...]
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    [...]
}
```

I use gradle 2.1 and android-gradle 0.14.4.

From my understanding, the given configuration should put compile-time-subproject in the classpath at compile-time and it should not be in the resulting apk. However I noticed that it is available at runtime as well (= in the apk).

Is this a bug in the android-gradle or is there anything wrong about my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not easily possible for android libraries to be used as provided. However java libraries can be given as provided.

As long as you only want the Android standard libary to be in your classpath when compiling the plugin and don't need resource or AndroidManifest.xml handling, you can make your library to a java project using the following

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def sdkVer = 23
def sdkDir = System.env.ANDROID_HOME
if (!sdkDir) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
}

sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += project.rootProject.files("$sdkDir/platforms/android-$sdkVer/android.jar")
```